# How to fix 'exec request failed on channel 0' in linux?

Tags: linux, ssh

All, 
I was trying to do pre- auth between two servers. I generated key pairs and I tried to copy the the public key to remote server. Got below error:

```
.ssh # cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh abcd@1.2.3.4 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh \ && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
abcd@1.2.3.4's password:
exec request failed on channel 0 <<<
```

Any suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion would be to use [ssh-copy-id](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) command.

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id "OPTIONS name@server"
```

Authenticate once this way and there after `ssh OPTIONS name@server` wont ask for your password again (unless you encrypt or protect your local ssh key).

Comment: Getting error while running ssh-copy-id command---------ssh-copy-id OPTIONS abcd@1.2.3.4
ssh: Could not resolve hostname OPTIONS: Name or service not known

Comment: What options did you use? Try putting everything after `ssh-copy-id` in quotes.